# Debug WordPress gettext function

Tags: translation, debug

The gettex function: ('__') receives the original string, in spite of the fact that the po file has the translation of the string. It happens accidentally.

Is there any method to find out the error?

Comment: Did you mean _returns_ original string? Do all other strings related to the file translate right?

Comment: Could it be using any special characters, and that's why it doesn't match?

Comment: Yes, it returns original string. There is no special character, The text is very simple: : 'View cart'. In this case WC uses ajax. Another original string: "
Showing 1–10 of 32 results" has singular and plural. Do you think this can be the problem?